# PowerBi embedded not loading - 500 internal server error

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded

We have an issue with a an embedded PowerBi that was working fine untill this morning. The problem is that the information is not loading and when we are watching the requests made by the page we see a 500 internal server error from the https://wabi-west-europe-redirect.analysis.windows.net/metadata/cluster

Print screen with the requests:
[PowerBi requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQNSQ.png)

We have updated the power bi client library to the latest version (powerbi-client v2.2.6), but the problem persists.

Comment: We managed to solve the issue. It was a problem with the authentication token. It seems that 2 parameters that mentioned to be optional in the documentation (exp and nbf) are now mandatory when creating the access token. Without these, you will get 500 internal server error when making a request to the server. Link to authentication documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/power-bi-embedded-app-token-flow